# Get DOM of AdSense Ad with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

What's up guys,

My goal is to get the full HTML code of an AdSense Ad in order to parse it. (not the dynamic js code, but the resulting HTML which is shown to the user). There is a legit reason to do this.

I'm using phantomJS for this and the following script:

```
//phantomjs
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://www.domain.com/directory/';

page.open(url, function (status) {
    var js = page.evaluate(function () {
        return document;
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(js)); 
    phantom.exit();
});
```

However, this only shows the javascript adsense code, not the HTML (the actual ad).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You're trying to click the ads through a script...?

Answer (score 1):

Try to wait a little before capturing the content. Ads are usually loaded asynchronously and may not be present when PhantomJS thinks that the page is already loaded.

```
page.open(url, function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(page.content);
        phantom.exit();
    }, 5000);
});
```

If the ad is in a frame, then you first need to change into the frame context with [`page.switchToFrame`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/switch-to-frame.html) and log the content with `page.frameContent`.

If this doesn't help, please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: the ad content in the iframe is not loaded it has a gpt api error googletag is undefined .

Comment: @GauravParashar I have noticed before that some ads are not properly loaded. I think this is an issue of how ads are loaded which PhantomJS cannot deal with. Maybe you should ask this on [GitHub](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues).